# Receiving message from server instantly while android screen is locked/is in a sleep

Tags: java, android, websocket, instant-messaging

I want to write a 'service' app that will be connected to a server, the server will send messages to the app and the phone will popup a notification to the screen instantly  upon receiving the message from the server even if the phone is locked. (like Whatsapp/Telegram etc..)

Push Notifications are not instant enough.

I was thinking about using WebSocket for that, but not sure it is the best approach.
What is the best approach?

Sample code will be appriciated!

Thanks.

Comment: "Push Notifications are not instant enough" -- that is what Whatsapp/Telegram etc. use.

Comment: Send the push message as high priority.  That's what all of the messaging apps do. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority